# C# - Responsive Winforms application positioning of pictureboxes

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm currently trying to create a **responsive** winforms application.

**What I try to archive:**

I want to create a winforms layout which will have a responsive UI.

**What is my problem:**

I've added three pictureboxes(Close button / minimize application button / maximize application button) to the first row of the TableLayoutPanel.

Those three pictureboxes are positioned in the top right corner of the form. But the location of those pictureboxes won't change once I click the maximize button. Theyre staying at the exact position which makes them literally centered on the maximized screen.

Screenshot showing it:

[image]

What could I do to fix this issue? I appreciate any kind of suggestions and help.

**What I have done so far:**

1. Added a TableLayoutPanel which contains 2 Rows.
2. Added a Panel to the first row containing a pictureBox.
3. Added 3 more pictureBoxes to the pictureBox which are the buttons shown in the screenshot to close / minimize / maximize the application.

Comment: Dock those icon picture box to right of the container. Also you can use anchor to `Top` and `Right` for them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, a `TableLayoutPanel` is quite a terrible control. It's hard to work with an has a noticeable performance issue once you get too many columns or rows. I suggest using two regular panels, one with `Dock = Top` and the other with `Dock = Fill` instead.
As for your buttons, I would position them inside the top panel, and set their anchor properties to Top and Right.

Further reading:

[`Control.Dock`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.dock(v=vs.110).aspx) property.
[`Control.Anchor`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.anchor(v=vs.110).aspx) property.

Comment: Since the user is looking for responsiveness which usually needs relative sizing (in percent) so `TableLayoutPanel` seems a good option.

Comment: Only if there are just a few cells. I've used it before with about 10 columns and 6 rows and performance was terrible. Had to remove it and position all the labels inside myself.

Answer (score 0):

You should anchor them to the right of their container. You should probably have a look at this: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.anchor(v=vs.110).aspx